# Finding strings with gaps that match a string in a list of strings

Tags: python

I have a list of strings that looks like this: `['ban*', 'c*rr*r', 'pl*s', pist*l ]`. I want to check if those strings have matching equivalents in another list of strings which is the following:

```
['banner', 'bannana', ban, 'carrer', 'clorror', 'planes', 'plots']
```

Comparing first string from the list I have`'banner'` and `'bannana'` and that would mean that there is a word that is matching that string ("ban*") So the `'*'` means that there can be one or more letters in that word.

Comment: What is the code you've written so far?

Comment: You can use [fnmatch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fnmatch.html#module-fnmatch), which does wildcard-style matching.

Answer (score 2):

Try this fnmatch approach

```
import fnmatch
lst = ['banner', 'bannana', 'ban', 'carrer', 'clorror', 'planes', 'plots']
f1 = fnmatch.filter(lst, 'ban*')
print (f1)
```

Output

```
['banner', 'bannana', 'ban']
```